# Workaround for nVidia OpenCL implementation using local (shared) memory to store function arguments

Tags: opencl, nvidia

According to nVidia's "OpenCL best practices guide",

> Shared memory holds the parameters or arguments that are passed to kernels at launch.

I have a kernel with a rather long argument list which needs all the available local memory (48kb). On Linux, CUDA10 and Tesla P100 I run into the problem of kernel arguments encroaching on the local memory (but for some reason, only for argument lists of 3 pointers or more, and only for 4 bytes, regardless of the number of arguments; and it does not happen at all on MacOS with the CUDA10 platform and nVidia driver installed).

In any case, the solution that the guide proposes is

> In kernels with long argument lists, it can be valuable to put some arguments into constant memory (and reference them there) rather than consume shared memory.

The problem is, all my arguments are pointers, and it does not seem to be possible to get the GPU address of a buffer in OpenCL by standard means. The only solution I can think of is to run a small kernel saving all the required pointers to some structure, and then using it as the only argument to the main kernel (marking it as `__constant`, probably). It seems like a hack though, and I suspect a physical address of a buffer may  be changed at any time by the OpenCL driver.

Is there a better workaround? Perhaps it is possible to turn off storing arguments in the local memory somehow?

Comment: "The problem is, all my arguments are pointers" I assume this means you have a lot of buffers? Can you consolidate these buffers? And no, pointer values aren't safe to persist across kernel runs.

Comment: I can consolidate some of them, but unfortunately I can't bring the argument number to 2 (to stop the driver from using local memory) - there are more sources of the data than that.

Comment: Would it be possible to pass a pointer to a struct of data to bring down the argument count to 2?

Comment: That is what they are proposing in the guide, but in my case that struct of data will have to contain pointers to buffers, which are hidden from the host.